# Constructor not defined Error in Test Class

Tags: apex

I have looked up all the similar questions but I could not find a solution to the error I was having.

> Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined:
>   [GenericConductorFromListViewController].(ApexPages.StandardSetController)
>   at line 35 column 53

This is the class

```
    public class GenericConductorFromListViewController {



      public String urlFieldName {get; set;}
      private String partnerServerUrl;
      private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
      private List<Id> recordIds = new List<Id>();


      public GenericConductorFromListViewController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;

        for (sObject sObj : controller.getSelected()){
          recordIds.add(sObj.Id);
        }
        partnerServerUrl = 'https://'+ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+'/services/Soap/u/26.0/'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
      } 

      public PageReference prepareConductorUrl() {
        PageReference conductorUrl = new PageReference('https://conductor.congamerge.com?');
        conductorUrl.getParameters().put('MOID', String.join(new List<Id>(recordIds),','));
        conductorUrl.getParameters().put('SessionId',  UserInfo.getSessionID());
        conductorUrl.getParameters().put('ServerUrl',  partnerServerUrl);
        conductorUrl.getParameters().put('UrlFieldName',  urlFieldName);

        return conductorUrl;
      }
    }
```

This is the Test class

I do not where I am doing wrong, I have  initialised the StandardSetController with sObject list and I am passing it to the class instance.

```
   @isTest
public with sharing class GenericConductorFromListViewController {
    /**
    * @description setup - test data setup method
    */
    @testSetup
    public static void setup(){
        List<Account> testAccounts = new List<Account>();

        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'ABC Company, Inc.';
        testAccounts.add(a);

        Account acct = new Account();
        acct.Name = 'XYZ Company, Inc.';
        testAccounts.add(acct);

        insert testAccounts;
    }
    /**
    * @description testMethod
    */
    public static testMethod void testMethod1() {

        List<sObject> accts = [Select Id From Account];


        ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accts);

        ssc.setSelected(accts);

        GenericConductorFromListViewController cn = new GenericConductorFromListViewController(ssc);

        cn.UrlFieldName = 'Download_Stress_Test_Notification_Letter__c';
        cn.prepareConductorUrl();

        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pr = cn.prepareConductorUrl();
        String fieldName = pr.getParameters().get('UrlFieldName');
        System.assertEquals('Download_Stress_Test_Notification_Letter__c',fieldName, 'The UrlFieldName parameter is not set' );
        Test.stopTest();

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test class can't have the same name as your base class. Salesforce thinks that you're trying to replace your controller class with this new version that doesn't have such a constructor defined. Change the name of your test class to something like `GenericConductorFromListViewTest` instead (note, symbols are limited to 40 characters).

Side note: [`testMethod`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_writing_tests.htm) has been deprecated. Use `@isTest` instead.

> The testMethod keyword is now deprecated. Use the `@isTest` annotation on classes and methods instead. The `@isTest` annotation on methods is equivalent to the `testMethod` keyword.